# Print the prime numbers from 1 to 100

Tags: c++

The below code doesn't seem to print the prime numbers from 1 through 100.
i am running two for loops in which am finding the modulus and then updating the count value (c).

```
using namespace std;
int main(){

    for(int i=0,c=0;i<100;i++){
        for(int j=1;j<=i;j++){
            if(i%j==0){
                c++;
            }

        }
         if(c<=2){
                cout<<i<<"\n";
            }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `c=0` is only done once for the entire program - you need to move it inside the outer loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
  for(int i=0,c=0;i<100;i++){
```

After first iteration of outer loop `c` becomes non zero and it keeps on getting incremented in further iterations.You need to set `c=0` for every iteration of outer loop.

```
  int c=0;
  for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
  c=0;
  ...
```

Also you might want to look at the optimizations while finding whether a number is prime or not, like you could run the inner loop from `2` to `sqrt(i)` and then checking for `c>0`.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a variable count of type integer;

```
 for(int i=1;i<=100;i++)
 {
       count=0;
       for(int j=i;j>=1;j--)
       {
              if(i%j==0)
              {
                   count++;
              }
       }
       if(count==2)
       {
              cout<<i<<"\n";
       }
 }
```